# How To convert New Data set according to dummy variables for validation

Tags: python, pandas, regression, logistic-regression

I am using a logistic regression model to predict a binary outcome.
Initially the model had 2 numeric variables which were converted into categorical. And finally dummy variables were created based on categories. Here is the example (apologies if its vague, I'm completely new to this field)

original df:

```
        Air_Humidity  Air_Temperature    
0            61.0            14.10       
1            61.0            14.21       
2            60.0            14.08       
3            60.0            14.08       
4            62.0            14.06       
5            65.0            18.36       
6            67.0            18.58       
7            65.0            18.52       
8            66.0            18.54       
9            64.0            18.60
```

Categorical Conversion using **qcut** (3 bins for humidity, 2 bins for temperature)

```
        Air_Humidity  Air_Temperature    
0            2            1       
1            2            1       
2            2            1       
3            2            1       
4            2            1       
5            3            2       
6            3            2       
7            3            2       
8            3            2       
9            2            2
```

Dummy variable df:

```
Air_Humidity_1  Air_Humidity_2  Air_Humidity_3  Air_Temperature_1   Air_Temperature_2    
      0               1               0               1               0   
      0               1               0               1               0   
      0               1               0               1               0   
      0               1               0               1               0   
      0               1               0               1               0   
      0               0               1               0               1   
      0               0               1               0               1   
      0               0               1               0               1   
      0               0               1               0               1   
      0               1               0               0               1
```

My Questions is: If I have a new sample of data. How do I convert it directly into dummy variable dataframe.? Which I can use to test the model using new data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for one column (`Air_Humidity`):

```
air_humidity_binned, air_humidity_bins = pd.qcut(df_train['Air_Humidity'], 3, retbins = True)
```

By setting `retbins = True` you're returning not only the binned variable, but also the borders of the bins, which you can use later to do binning on the test set.

Adjustment in case values on the test set are out of bounds for the training set:

```
air_humidity_bins = np.concatenate(([-np.inf], air_humidity_bins[1:-1], [np.inf]))
```

Then to get a binned variable on the test set:

```
air_humidity_binned_test = pd.qcut(df_test['Air_Humidity'], air_humidity_bins)
```

For a more streamlined way of doing this you can try sklearn's `KBinsDiscretizer` (with `strategy='quantile'`) which follows the usual fit-transform pattern.